# Why can I not install the latest version of gscan2pdf?

Tags: updates, pdf, scanning

I installed gscan2pdf 0.9.? something from the Software Center. It has bugs in it that will not allow me to import a pdf with images without gscan only importing the images and ignoring the text.

I found this online and read that it is fixed in gscan2pdf-1.0.4 which is available on Sourceforge. Whenever I try to install it thought it, the install fails and Synaptic will not update past 0.9. Why is this and how can I get gscan2pdf-1.0.4 on my computer? Thank you.

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using?  Can you add to your question what instructions you are using to install 1.0.4 and also what errors you are getting when installing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use `gscan2pdf` > 1.0 on Ubuntu 11.04 and without problem I use on current Ubuntu 12.04 from Jeffrey Ratcliffe PPA: https://launchpad.net/~jeffreyratcliffe/+archive/ppa

Comment: Thank you for the help. I had to add the ppa for jeffreyratcliffe to get the software center to update to the newest version. Before i was trying to download it directly from sourceforge and install it, something I have not done before without instruction and I was probably doing it wrong. Thank everyone's help!

Comment: Fortunately I got it to update by adding the repository you mentioned but it still will not open a pdf with images with the text. I have posted another question specific to this topic here. http://askubuntu.com/questions/133317/why-wont-gscan2pdf-open-a-pdf-with-images-and-text-and-not-just-the-images

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is specific about gcan2pdfthat you need, but the installed 'Simplescan' has an output option to save a scannned image as a PDF. Would that help??